# How to get buttons working on Badger2040 in Tinygo

Tags: rp2040, tinygo

I've been trying to access the Badger2040 buttons through Tinygo and not having any luck (I have succeeded in CircuitPython before).

When I try to change the led state based on Button A, the led is switched on and never switches off:

```
package main

import (
    "machine"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    led := machine.LED
    led.Configure(machine.PinConfig{Mode: machine.PinOutput})

    button_a := machine.BUTTON_A
    button_a.Configure(machine.PinConfig{Mode: machine.PinInputPullup})

    for {
        led.Set(button_a.Get())
        time.Sleep(time.Second / 4)
    }
}
```

If I change the led.Set to pass in `!button_a.Get()` then the led is always off.

It appears that button_a.Get() is always returning true.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based this on the included TinyGo examples (not for the Badger2040) - which used PinInputPullup - but it turns out the Badger2040 **needs to use PinInputPulldown**, i.e. configure the button like this:

```
    button_a.Configure(machine.PinConfig{Mode: machine.PinInputPulldown})
```

Note that this works for the up/down/a/b/c buttons.  The user button also toggles, but is inverted, i.e. returns true when not pressed.